# paper-tabs tab borders - Polymer

Tags: html, css, polymer

I have `paper-tabs` set up but I would like dividers between each of the tabs.

I currently have it set up like this:

**css**

```
paper-tabs {
    color: blue;
    background: var(--light-primary-color);
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--accent-color); 
}

paper-tab {
    border-right: 1px solid var(--divider-color);
    --paper-tab-ink: var(--default-primary-color);
}

paper-tab:last-child {
    border: none ;
}
```

**html**

```
<paper-tabs selected="0" scrollable>
    <paper-tab>NUMBER ONE ITEM</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
    <paper-tab>THE THIRD ITEM</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

However I have found that adding a border to the `paper-tab` element causes the border to be above the selection bar.

**gif**

[image]

**image**

[image]

Does anybody have any thoughts on how to correct this so the selection bar is in front of the border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property. Add `z-index` for the selection-bar greater than the `z-index` of the `paper-tab` border.

**CSS:**

```
paper-tabs {
    color: blue;
    background: var(--light-primary-color);
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color: var(--accent-color);
    
    --paper-tabs-selection-bar:{
      z-index:1;
    }
  }
```

Plnkr:  [Sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/wmJ3xc?p=preview)

Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I thought it may be something like this but wasn't sure on how to get it exactly. It's been bothering me for weeks!#]